# can't execute command replicate db (START ALL SLAVES)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I made 2 master db server replications into 1 slave db server, but got an error when running the following command:

```
stop slave;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='xx.xx.xx.1',MASTER_USER='xxxx',MASTER_PASSWORD='xxxx',MASTER_LOG_FILE='mariadb-bin.000001',MASTER_LOG_POS=111;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='xx.xx.xx.2',MASTER_USER='xxxx',MASTER_PASSWORD='xxxx',MASTER_LOG_FILE='mariadb-bin.000002',MASTER_LOG_POS=2222;
start all slaves;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'all slaves' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You are running that on one Slave.  So it does not make sense to say "all slaves".  Just say `START SLAVE;`.

I think `START ALL SLAVES` refers to downstream slaves.  It is not available until MariaDB 10.0.